# How to add links to chart.js (Doughnut Charts)?

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, chart.js

I would like to add links to doughnut charts to be able to send the user for a page with the records filtered by the clicked option.

For example [here](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#doughnut-pie-chart-introduction), if the user click on "Green", I want to send the user to a page that will show all "Green" records.

I didn't find a easy way to do that, and tried something like this that isn't working yet:

(I added a attribute "filter" with the "id" that I need to filter it)

```
var data = [
  {
    value: 300,
    color:"#F7464A",
    highlight: "#FF5A5E",
    label: "Red",
    filter: 1
  },
  {
    value: 50,
    color: "#46BFBD",
    highlight: "#5AD3D1",
    label: "Green",
    filter: 2
  },
  {
    value: 100,
    color: "#FDB45C",
    highlight: "#FFC870",
    label: "Yellow",
    filter: 3
  }
]

$(document).ready(
    function () {
        $("#chart").click(
            function(evt){
                var activePoints = chart.getSegmentsAtEvent(evt);
                var url = "http://example.com/?grid[f][collor][]=" + activePoints[0].filter
                alert(url);
            }
        );
    }
);
```

I'm not being able to get the attribute "filter" using "activePoints[0].filter"

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding custom properties in JSON is a feature that may be on the roadmap for v2 (https://github.com/nnnick/Chart.js/issues/1185). As it currently stands, you can add properties in javascript doing something like this:

```
var segments = chart.segments;
for (var i = 0; i < segments.length; i++) {
  segments[i].filter = i+1;
}
```

Here's a jsfiddle with the filter/id property loading in the url (http://jsfiddle.net/tcy74pcc/1/):

If you want to do this with a chart based on points rather than segments, here's a post with a similar solution for lines:
[Displaying custom dataset properties in tooltip in chart.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29176778/displaying-custom-dataset-properties-in-tooltip-in-chart-js)

Hope that helps. Best of luck!

Comment: Yes, that works for me. I will use your code. 
(but I hope they will improve that for new versions)

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

getSegmentsAtEvent is now deprecated. Use getElementsAtEvent instead.

Here's the complete function with added bonus of having dynamic colors for each segment.

```
    var piChart = function (ctx, labelName, labels, values, filters) {
        var colors = dynamicColors(values.length)

        var data = {
            labels: labels,
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: labelName,
                    backgroundColor: colors.backColors,
                    hoverBackgroundColor: colors.highColors,
                    borderColor: colors.borders,
                    hoverBorderColor: colors.borders,
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    data: values
                }
            ]
        };

        var pieChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: "pie",
            data: data
        });


        if (filters != null) {
            ctx.click(
               function (evt) {
                   var activePoints = pieChart.getElementAtEvent(evt);
                   if (activePoints.length > 0) {
                       var index = activePoints[0]["_index"];
                       location.href = filters[index];
                   }
               });
        }
    }

    var dynamicColors = function (count) {
        var backColors = [];
        var highColors = [];
        var borders = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
            var g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
            var b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
            var backColor = "rgba(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + ", 0.4)";
            var highColor = "rgba(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + ", 0.8)";
            var border = "rgba(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + ", 1)";

            backColors.push(backColor);
            highColors.push(highColor);
            borders.push(border);
        }
```

Comment: That is important. Thank you.

Comment: This answer works for version 2.  As of version 3, `getElementsAtEvent` has been replaced with `getElementsAtEventForMode`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73808768) for an example.