# I search additive options on chartsjs

Tags: chart.js

I use chartsjs, bar type as it is written [here](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html) 
It works for me, but I searched for some features I did not get in this docs:

a) I work with votes, so my results can not have decimal values, so having small values I get decimals in Y coordinates.
Are there some options to show only integer in Y coordinates ?

b) If there is a way by clicking on some element to trigger js function with parameters of the selected element?
I would like to redirect to some other page with details of the selected data.

c) As I vote results(which can be valid/invalid) if there is a way in 1 bar to show 2 values(color and number)?

Thanks!

Comment: Everything you want is possible. Have you tried any methods? you just simply asking like my manager ;)

Comment: I read the docs and did not find similar methods. Could you please to point at them : I will try.

Comment: Try to write function in js for y-axis data.

Comment: Could you, please, a link to such example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please code or search something threw the internet and then ask question. Below are the links that you are looking for I guess.

```
a) https://jsfiddle.net/leighking2/1vy6hdjk/

b) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45980436/chart-js-link-to-other-page-when-click-on-specific-section-in-chart

 c) https://jsfiddle.net/sdfx/hwx9awgn/
```