# Add link to Chart JS Sections

Tags: javascript, charts, pie-chart

I have a pie chart using CharJS library, very similar to this [link](https://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/charts/pie.html). And a config like this one:

```
        var config = {
            type: 'pie',
            data: {
                datasets: [{
                    data: [
                        randomScalingFactor(),
                        randomScalingFactor(),
                        randomScalingFactor(),
                        randomScalingFactor(),
                        randomScalingFactor(),
                    ],
                    backgroundColor: [
                        window.chartColors.red,
                        window.chartColors.orange,
                        window.chartColors.yellow,
                        window.chartColors.green,
                        window.chartColors.blue,
                    ],
                    label: 'Dataset 1'
                }],
                labels: [
                    'Red',
                    'Orange',
                    'Yellow',
                    'Green',
                    'Blue'
                ]
            },
            options: {
                responsive: true
            }
        };
```

Any idea how can I open a specific link when user click() on each section of this pie (unique link for each unique section)?

Comment: This should help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45980436/chart-js-link-to-other-page-when-click-on-specific-section-in-chart

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful