# How to add on click event to chart js

Tags: javascript, ajax, django-views, chart.js, linechart

Hello I have a question concerning js charts. I have already created one in django application and i want to generate a javascript alert by clicking a certain point in the chart.
How can the alert get the value of the point that i choose?
For example with the value 92 like what is shown in the figure below:
[image]

Comment: [check it out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45980436/chart-js-link-to-other-page-when-click-on-specific-section-in-chart),hope this helps .

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with an `onClick` even handler as follows:

```
onClick: (event, elements, chart) => {
  if (elements[0]) {            
     const i = elements[0].index;
     alert(chart.data.labels[i] + ': ' + chart.data.datasets[0].data[i]);
  }
}
```

Please take a look at below runnable code and see how it works.

```js
new Chart('myChart', {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
  labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
      borderColor: '#a00'
    }]
  },
  options: {
    onClick: (event, elements, chart) => {
      if (elements[0]) {            
         const i = elements[0].index;
         alert(chart.data.labels[i] + ': ' + chart.data.datasets[0].data[i]);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.7.1/chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="95"></canvas>
```