# Chart.js - open link with chart item in link

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have a chart that shows hits by instagram user and each pie slice represents a user. I am trying add the functionality of opening the Instagram profile by clicking the slice that represents the user. I am able to use [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45980436/chart-js-link-to-other-page-when-click-on-specific-section-in-chart) to have each slice open a new tab, but unsure how to use the data within the link. The number of slices changes often as the data will come from a JSON updated routinely, so I can't hardcode the account links as the above question does.

The link would be in a format: `https://www.instagram.com/${username}`

```js
const xData = ['meta', 'codepen', 'github'];
const yData = [10,18,22];

 new Chart("polarChart", {
            type: 'polarArea',
            data: {
                labels: xData,
                datasets: [{
                    data: yData,
                    backgroundColor: "rgba(50, 50, 50,0.7)",
                }]
            }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.js"></script>
<canvas id="polarChart"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe to simply, you could leverage on `onClick` option of chartjs, instead of activate the `onclick` on the canvas. The `onClick` option can also pass to you the clicked element and you don't have to invoke the `getElementByEvent`.

```js
const xData = ['meta', 'codepen', 'github'];
const yData = [10,18,22];

const ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
const polarChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'polarArea',
  data: {
    labels: xData,
    datasets: [{
      data: yData,
      backgroundColor: "rgba(50, 50, 50,0.7)",
    }]
  },
  options: {
    onClick(event, elements) {
      if (elements.length === 1) {
        const selected = xData[elements[0]._index];
        // doesn't open the window because not allowed here
        window.alert(`https://www.instagram.com/${selected}`);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.myChartDiv {
  max-width: 600px;
  max-height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.9.4/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>
<div class="myChartDiv">
  <canvas id="myChart" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I may have figured out a solution, but not sure if it's the most robust. This is working in a CodePen, but not in the Stack Overflow snippet for me.

```js
var canvasP = document.getElementById("polarChart");


const xData = ['meta', 'codepen', 'github'];
const yData = [10,18,22];

 const polarChart = new Chart("polarChart", {
 type: 'polarArea',
   data: {
     labels: xData,
     datasets: [{
       data: yData,
       backgroundColor: "rgba(50, 50, 50,0.7)",
     }]
   }
});

canvasP.onclick = function(e) {
  var slice = polarChart.getElementAtEvent(e);
  if (!slice.length) return; // return if not clicked on slice
  var label = slice[0]._model.label;
  for(let i=0; i<xData.length; i++) {
    let currUser = xData[i];
    switch (label) {
      case xData[i]:
        window.open(`https://www.instagram.com/${currUser}`);
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.js"></script>
<canvas id="polarChart"></canvas>
```

Comment: Link the codepen

Comment: Also tested in js Bin which worked too and linked here: https://jsbin.com/vosesawele/edit?html,js,output

Comment: It cant open in the sanbox in StackOverflow because of the following. `Blocked opening 'https://www.instagram.com/codepen' in a new window because the request was made in a sandboxed frame whose 'allow-popups' permission is not set.`