# add url in the pie chart

Tags: javascript, php, chart.js

[image]

Like this picture. I want to add 3 urls. (URL) => [A,B,C]   When the user clicks on one of the pie charts. A new page will open.I want to know how to add url params in the javascript.

Is change `datasets`-`data` ?

```js
const data = {
  labels: [
    'Red',
    'Blue',
    'Yellow'
  ],
  datasets: [{
    label: 'My First Dataset',
    data: [300, 50, 100],
    backgroundColor: [
      'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
      'rgb(54, 162, 235)',
      'rgb(255, 205, 86)'
    ],
    hoverOffset: 4
  }]
};
```

EMM.  I'm  not to try everything. I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Please look into this thread, this may resolve your issue : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45980436/chart-js-link-to-other-page-when-click-on-specific-section-in-chart